# Puppeteer / Chrome DevTools: retrieve certificate for intermediate server in a redirect chain

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

### **tl;dr**

Is there a way to fetch certificates for all intermediates servers involved in a redirect chain and not only the final server?

### **Details**

Lets say we have a URL (e.g., `https://fastlane.ci`) that redirects (`HTTP 3xx`) to another
one (e.g., `https://github.com/fastlane/ci`). Using the following code:

```js
const session = await page.target().createCDPSession()
await session.send('Network.enable')
await page.goto('https://fastlane.ci')
await session.send('Network.getCertificate', { origin: 'https://github.com' })
```

I can get the x.509 cert provided by `github.com`. If I change `origin` to `https://fastlane.ci`, the result would be empty. I can, however, see in `SecurityDetail`s that for the initial response (HTTP redirect) the certificate is retrieved and parsed somewhere in the background.

**I need raw certificates. How can I get them over the DevTools API?**

Comment: This is how I get my DER certificates, if response.securityDetails() is not null:

certs = await page._client.send('Network.getCertificate', {origin: response_url.toString()});

However, it's not working for status code 503, dunno why - response.securityDetails() is not empty and I can see the cert's content via debugger, but the above method results in null :(